# Iterating through custom structure unifrom array in OpenGL 4.5

Tags: debugging, opengl, glsl, shader

I am attempting to iterate through a uniform array of customly defined structures in OpenGL 4.5 but my application crashes with an invalid operation enumerator.

My fragment shader looks as:

```
#version 450

struct Light
{
  vec4 position;//intensity here as well
  vec4 color;
};

in vec3 normal;//Normal to the vertex
in vec3 vertexPos;//True position of the vertex (i.e it's location in space)
in vec2 texture_coord;

out vec4 outColor;//Final color of the pixel

uniform sampler2D text;
uniform samplerCubeArray depth_maps;
uniform Light lights[];

uniform vec4 color = vec4(1);//Default color
//TODO: make this an array
//uniform vec3 lum = vec3(100,90,15); vec3(80,70,10);//A unique light position

uniform vec3 lums[2] = {vec3(80,70,10), vec3(100,90,15)};
uniform vec3 cameraPos = vec3(0);//The position of the camera in the world
uniform vec3 cameraDir = vec3(0);

void main()
{
    outColor = vec4(0);
    for(uint i=0 ; i<2; i++)
    {
        vec4 color = vec4(0);
        vec3 lum = lights[i].position.xyz;
        vec3 l = vec3(lum-vertexPos);
        if(length(l)>0)
            l = normalize(l);
        vec3 c = vec3(texture(text,abs(texture_coord)));
        vec3 n = normalize(normal);
        vec3 e = cameraPos-vertexPos;
        e = normalize(e);
        vec3 h = normalize(e+l);

        color = vec4(c*(vec3(0.5)+0.5*max(0,dot(n,l))) + 
            vec3(0.1)*max(0,pow(dot(h,n), 100)), 1);

        vec3 temp = vertexPos-lum; 

        float test = texture(depth_maps, vec4(temp, 1)).r;
        double d = length(temp);

        if(d>test*256 + 0.5)
            color = vec4(test/2);

        outColor += color;
    }

    outColor = outColor/2.f;
}
```

If you replace the index in the assignment operator to a constant, i.e you write `vec3 lum = lights[0].position.xyz;` or `vec3 lum = lights[1].position.xyz;`

There is no error (but of course the final image is wrong).

However if instead I try to set it dynamically to the vec3 array, i.e I write:

```
vec3 lum = lums[i];
```

Things work as expected.

Why can't I iterate through my Light array? Is it because it's a custom defined structure?

Edit:

Adding cpp code that sets up shadow maps since it as requested

Draw a shadow map

```
void Renderer::draw_shadow_maps(vector<Light> &lights)
{
    current_program = shading_programs[SHADER_DEPTH].programID;
    glUseProgram(current_program);

    //shadow_maps.resize(lights.size());

    glViewport(0, 0, 2048, 2048);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FBOs[FBO_SHADOW_MAP]);

    for(uint i=0; i<lights.size(); i++)
    {
        glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, shadow_maps[0].textureID, 0);

        load_uniform((int)i, "map_index");

        glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE); 
        glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);

        if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        {
            if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER)==GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT)
                cerr << "shadow map was not initialized properly" << endl;
            exit(0);
        }

        glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        setup_light_perspectives(current_program, lights[i]);
        draw();
    }
}
```

Creating a shadow map atlas:

```
Shadow_Map::Shadow_Map()
{
    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY, textureID);
    glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY,1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F, 2048, 2048, 6*10);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);  

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0);
    openGLerror();
}
```

Passing the information to the GPU:

```
void Shadow_Map::load_to_GPU(GLuint program)
{   
    glUseProgram(program);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY, textureID);

    string name = "depth_maps";

    GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation(program, name.c_str());
    if(loc == GL_INVALID_VALUE || loc==GL_INVALID_OPERATION)
    {
        cerr << "Error returned when trying to find depth_map uniform."
            << "\nuniform: " << name 
            << "\nError num: " << loc
            << endl;
        return;
    }

    glUniform1i(loc,1);
}
```

Comment: What does the code that sets the uniforms look like?

Comment: "*`loc == GL_INVALID_VALUE || loc==GL_INVALID_OPERATION`*" Yeah, that's not how [OpenGL errors work](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Error). At all. Also, where's the rest of the code? Where do you get the OpenGL error that "crashes" your program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> uniform Light lights[];
> ```

[Arrays in GLSL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Arrays) almost always must have a statically-defined size. Here are the exceptions:

1. You're allowed to forward declare an array without a size, but only if you redeclare it later with a size.
2. The variable is the [last member of a shader storage block](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Interface_Block_(GLSL)#Shader_storage_blocks).
3. The variable (or interface block) is a shader-stage input/output qualified variable/block, and the input/output to that stage is arrayed.